# Very long question titles don't wrap

Tags: bug, title

A picture is worth a thousand words (Sorry for my bad coloring skills):

[image: Preview]

I think these very long question titles should wrap. I have found this bug while exploring a question in Stack Overflow.

I am using Windows 10, Firefox 90.0.1.

Comment: I can paste the link of this question if needed to reproduce, but I am not sure about Meta affects and other complicated stuff.

Comment: I think the title did wrap... else the part in quotes would have been on the same line. I guess the limit is till the 'Ask Question' button. (Also that is a bad question title)

Comment: That is one long "word" (69 characters). The wrapping doesn't automatically hyphenate words to split then across lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Side-by-side question review with long title can display overlapping title text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407432/side-by-side-question-review-with-long-title-can-display-overlapping-title-text). The issue's been reported before in relation to review queues, but the underlying root cause is the same (I am not sure if that should even be considered an issue)